# XMLHttpRequest CORS in ie11?

Tags: javascript

I used  XMLHttpRequest in my project with post method.
My code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8887/', true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
req.send("Test");
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome but IE11 and Edge not working (I see error: access denied). I have server on IP:https://129.168.10.101/myapplication and try cross domain in browser IE11 open Internet option and added trusted sites http://127.0.0.1 and https://129.168.10.101/myapplication but it's not working. Is it possible to cross domain to localhost in IE or Edge?

Thanks for help

Jarek

Comment: IE11 has native support for CORS. You've misidentified your problem.

Comment: Which serverside technology you are using

Comment: Possibly an issue with port numbers or protocol differences - show console errors

Comment: "IE11 and Edge not working" it is not enough to detect the problem. Please detail the error you are receiving

Comment: Possibly an issue with an HTTPS trying to access HTTP and thus having mixed security levels. (That's a major no-no in general).

Comment: @Quentin IE11's definition of "Same Origin" is [slightly different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#IE_Exceptions) from other browsers.

Comment: @Amy — Those exceptions can cause it to accept two origins as being the same (and not need CORS) when they should be different. The problem described here is that it is rejecting two origins despite CORS granting permission.

Comment: I'm using weblogic and my application is written Java and Wicket